# Do you have to have a PhD to be a "research scientist"?

Tags: career-path, titles

I'm graduating from my master's degree at MIT this summer and I have a chance to stay for another year as an employee in my current lab while I apply for PhD programs. I'd love to do that because I love the current grant I am working on, I love the topic, the people and the PI.

My only hesitation is that there seems to be very limited titles in academia for one who is not a graduate student and does not have a PhD. The truth is, I do not want to be a "lab tech." I want to start becoming autonomous in the field I did my master's and becoming a lab tech is the exact opposite of being an independent researcher (based on my understanding).

I feel like if I start my year-long employment with the agreement with my PI that I'll continue work on my current research but with the "lab tech" title, the post-doc who supervises my work will treat me like a lab tech!

Therefore, I'd like to be a "research scientist" for the next year, but do I have to have a PhD for that? Or, what other titles are there besides a lab tech for people who wants to do research without a PhD in academia?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. You only want a better title?

Comment: yes, @Najib. I added the details to the last paragraph of the question above as an edit.

Comment: @user93363 Your question was fine before, you should focus a little bit on editing it down to be more concise and remove the rant at the end.

Comment: All I meant to say in that verbose paragraph was that I want the responsibility and the title that comes with it, which is not a lab tech (also, I do not want to be derogatory towards the labtech title, it's just not what I want).

Comment: @user93363 I suggested an edit that will make your question more readable and more inviting to others to respond.

Comment: @Azor oh, thanks very much for taking the time to edit my initial post! It's my first time posting a question here and I had gone into some tangential details as I composed my inquiry I guess.

Comment: It depends. At least SOME place would let you become a RS w/o a PhD.

Comment: @user93363 No problem. People here like to see polished questions.

Answer (score 8):

**Titles depend on institution.** In industry, you can be a "research scientist" with no particular degree. In a university, a "research scientist" may be a catch-all term for scientific employees, or it may be a parallel track with similar prestige to a professorship (with similarly high standards). I do not know what MIT's system is.

**Your job responsibilities will depend on your boss (advisor) far more than your title.** If your advisor is on board with you continuing your current research, then great; this will be true regardless of your title. If they are doing you a favor allowing you to remain employed while you apply for PhD programs, then they may expect you to do "lab tech" type work.

**It's certainly a good idea to discuss your title, responsibilities and goals with your advisor before accepting the position.** But I wouldn't be too concerned about the title. If this were a permanent position for you, I might agree that "lab tech" would be an unfortunate title, and might have unfortunate implications about your ability to participate in original research (especially since you would have to consider your position if your supervisor moves on). But since this is just a temporary stop-gap until grad school, I would focus this conversation on your responsibilities and goals.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no. You only need someone willing to hire you for the role to have it. I know people with only a BS who transitioned from technician in an academic lab to research scientist there (and got a big pay increase in the process). Conversely you don't need a different title to be given independence. I know of technicians (who went on to grad school) who were relied on to make major decisions and suggest new projects.

A longer answer is that you will always be at a disadvantage in the research world without those letters, and constantly feeling like you must prove you are deserving of independence before you get it. A PhD is commonly described as training to be an independent researcher. Some of the smartest people I know never advanced beyond the BS and as a result were beset by headaches such as your concern about the postdoc. In academia such pecking orders tend to get taken to the extreme, too.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a description for MIT specifically, and I'm sure this varies by university and country, but no, a PhD is not a universal requirement for the title "Research Scientist."

At the University of Washington, the only requirement is a bachelor's degree to be a [Research Scientist I](https://hr.uw.edu/files/comp/researchsciengr/1492.php). In fact, it's not until [Research Scientist IV](https://hr.uw.edu/files/comp/researchsciengr/1495.php) that a PhD is a minimum qualification, and even then, "Bachelor's degree candidates with exceptional qualifications may be considered." 
A PhD is required to be a [Senior Research Scientist](https://hr.uw.edu/files/comp/researchsciengr/1496.php), however.

On the flip side, [at Harvard](https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/40/2017/07/nonfacresearchgrid11-12-2015.pdf), a PhD is required to be any level of a "Research Scientist."

So, in short, this will depend on the policies at your institution, and you should look them up before you bring up with your PI about her hiring you on as a "Research Scientist" and not whatever the official title for a "lab tech" is.

Personally, I wouldn't be as dismissive as Najib is in the comments. Having a conversation about your role/responsibilities is a good thing to have, and if you don't want the role of a lab tech, then you'll know you should look elsewhere.

In terms of other titles, you may also look for a "Research Analyst" or "Research Technologist."

Comment: I am not sure what the last paragraph of your answer is for. My comment is asking if OP really only wants a better title, as some parts of the answer say, or actually additional responsibilities/tasks, as other parts of the answer say. Hence my question, "You only want a better title?", to which you will note that OP answered "yes". If you view something dismissive in these six words, it's only in your eyes.

Comment: Thanks for your response Azor, I did check the MIT policies on "research scientist" positions, but it was a bit ambigious (https://policies-procedures.mit.edu/node/45/#sub2).

Comment: Oh also, I did not take Najib's comment as dismissive at all. Thanks you both for the responses.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I didn't mean to cause offense. I thought it was fairly clear the OP didn't want to be a lab tech, and wanted their title to reflect that. I don't think any part of the original question suggested they "really only wanted a better title" (did you mean "question," btw?), which may explain why I interpreted your comment differently than you intended it to be read.

Comment: @user93363 check out section 5.2.3 your title would probably be technical assistant or research specialist

Comment: Under "5.2.2 Research Scientist, Research Engineer, Research Associate" it says the following: "They hold an advanced degree appropriate to the field of research or a combination of related education and high-level research."
When I google "advanced degree" for its definition, it seems to be a graduate degree --either a master's or a PhD. Since I have the former (in fact, I have a dual master's degree, both from MIT), I figured I might be eligible for a research scientist position. I'm curious why you thought otherwise @StrongBad ?

Comment: @qwerty In practice, the MIT policy is that "research scientist" requires a a doctoral degree (or other terminal degree).  They do leave things a bit hazy, so that they can hire people who have slightly lower academic qualifications but already have extensive career accomplishments.  For somebody with only a masters degree and no outside accomplishments, "research scientist" is at least two pay grades too high to aim for.  To wit, a graduate student would normally be a "research assistant"; above that, a normal post-doc is a "research associate"; and "research scientist" is yet higher.

Answer (score 0):

Job titles and the associated requirements will vary from university to university (and possibly within schools of the same university). For MIT those policies are given at https://policies-procedures.mit.edu/. For your type of position, the relevant sections are [5.2.2 Research Scientist, Research Engineer, Research Associate](https://policies-procedures.mit.edu/node/45/#sub2) and [5.2.3 Research Specialist, Technical Associate, Technical Assistant](https://policies-procedures.mit.edu/node/45/#sub3). The wording of sections is very similar, with the key difference being Research Scientists

> contribute significantly to the design and execution of experiments in research projects. They work in collaboration with the principal investigator.

and Research Specialists

> provide professional, technical, or other support service to a research project or program under the direction of a principal investigator.

For the position you are describing, while a PI may informally say you are a collaborator, when push comes to shove it is an unequal relationship and you are working under the direction of the PI.

That said, what you do is generally more important than the title you hold. Your treatment within the group will not depend so much on your title as on the roles and responsibilities your PI assigns you (possibly through the post doc). If the PI expects you to do your own thing, then you will be independent, regardless of the title. If the PI expects you to turn the crank while observed by the post doc, then you will be a monkey regardless of the title. You need to discuss your roles and responsibilities prior to taking the job.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Being a scientist requires no formal degree. It is a systematic approach to data analysis and interpolation. While a degree could help teach you how to think, it’s very apathetic to what is needed. Based on most research today, I’d argue many who hold the title are not even science driven. If you are able to objectively look at data with no bias and draw a conclusion based on the data, technically you are a scientist.

People value too much what other people choose as your title. That is all just people, and true science does not need validation, to create a theory. Validation comes from the repeatable of the scientific process and deduced conclusions. Everyone here is talking about clout and validation though a governed body that almost certainly has bias built in.

Ask yourself, what formal training did all of the most revered scientists have? None, they went against the grain and let the data guide them. I hate people think universities have a monopoly on science. They are not the gatekeepers. They should be informed by science, not police it and decide what is right based on the current accepted principles. That is a flawed way to think.

Answer (score -5):

The  other  tittle   is   "research assistant"   Yes, people   with master's   degrees   do  get hired  as   research  assistants.   I know  one  person   who  was  hired   by  the  Oklahoma   Geological  survey   as   research  assistant  while  he  was  working  on  his  M.S.  in geology   and   he  remained   employed  as  a  research   assistant. "Research  assistant"  is  his  job  title,  or  was.

How  you   are  treated  by  someone   else  often   depends  on  how  you  treat  them,   if  you  have  no  personal  respect  for  the  post-doc  who  is  directing  your  research,  why   should  that  post-doc  respect  you.  The  post-doc  has  more  life   experience  in   academia  than you   do.

You   don't  HAVE  to  stay  in   academia.   y\ou CAN  go  to  work  for  the  federal   government  I  am  assuming   you  are  in  the  United States)  or  industry   or  businesses   with  master's   degree.   I  talked  to   someone    within  the last  month   whose  daughter   got  two   bachelor's  degrees  and  master's  degree     and  her  mother  says  she LOVES her  job.

I  have  THREE  bachelor's   degree  AND   an M.S.  in   geology.   Yes,  i  wanted  to  get  Ph.D  18  and  15  years   ago.   but  I   would  have  had  to   apply    and  to  another   university's  Ph.D.  program  AND   be  admitted    and  then  i  would  have  to MOVE  to  another   state...  I've  come  to  accept  the   fact   that  i no longer  have    the  physical  stamina   to   get   a  Ph.D.   and  now  my  knowledge  is  OUTDATED   because  i haven't  really kept  up   with  academic  literature.  Even   second  master's  degree    may not  be   worth  the  investment  of   another 3 years  of TIME,  especially since  i might  end up  in   assisted  living  before  i   could  graduate.,   and   that master's   degree  program  REQUIRES   at  LEAST   2  internships.  In August,  2003  i  was  told  by  an  assistant    graduate  college   dean  that  if  i  wa NOT  admitted  into  college  degree  program,   the university  did not  need  ow  want  me  because  Everyone   was  going  back   to  school.   that  was  !5 YEARS   ago.  That  is  still   true  TODAY.

You HAVE  a  job. Do you   want  to keep    that  job,  even if you   are  doing  SOMEONE ELSE'S   research,   or  not  just   because    you     think   you   will be    treated     and  not  get  the  respect   YOU  think you  deserve/  Respect  is  EARNED,  not   granted.   You CANNOT DEMAND    respect and kindness  form  someone  else. I've   had  that  happen   TO ME,   and  it   was   the MOST  INSULTING   thing   that  I've   EVER  had  happen  to me.